# How to implement neural network using FPGA?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, verilog, hardware, intel-fpga

I want to design neural networks using FPGAs and make neuromorphic chip. Is there a tutorial or course to learn how to do that and to implement neural network using FPGA especially for evaluating the hardware cost of the neural network model?

Comment: Neurotrophic synthesis is to emulate a massively parallel analog computer at slow speeds.

Comment: I think you have learn fuzzy logic

Comment: Why specifically FPGAs?  Would you not want an FPGA plus something to reprogram it on the fly?  

Anyway is [this](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/introduction-to-neural-networks/anatomy) the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: "Neural Networks using FPGA" gives a 1000 results on Google, especially research papers. READ THEM. Good luck

Comment: @KH as far as I know, neural networks have fixed shapes, and the weights of the links are updated during the training process. The weights are data processed by the FPGA.

Answer (score 1):

With "implementing a neural network" I reckon you mean the inference part. This mathematically means that you want to do a lot of matrix multiplication, possibly at low precision.

The DSP blocks on Fpga are not that helpful as they target higher precision calculations.

Using fabric logic to implement such matrix multiplication is quite expensive and rather slow.

An ASIC will be much better at high throughput matrix multiplication. Dedicated units exist e.g. googles Tensor processing units or nvidia's Tensor cores.

Even without dedicated units GPUs will be much faster per € in inference..FPGA might be more efficient per W though as you calculate no overhead if you define exactly the units you need.

Comment: I think this is the kind of high-level info the OP was looking for. Reading a heap of scientific papers would not help in this sense, since as a beginner it is difficult to figure out full pictures.